# Can't read RGBC data from TCS34725 RGB Sensor using AVR and Atmega16

Tags: sensor, avr, embedded, atmega, rgb

For my project, I need to read the RGBC data from a TCS34725 RGB Sensor using the Atmega16 and AVR. It should be able to classify between the colors Red, Green, Blue and Clear light. Therefore I made a TCS library, with routines to enable and init the gain and integration time of the sensor, as well as reading routines to get the data from the sensor. However, I get no output on the LCD Display. Here is the full code below:

tcs34725.h:

```c
#ifndef TCS34725_H_
#define TCS34725_H_

#define F_CPU   12000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>

#include "iic.h"

// sensor addresses and registers
#define TCS_DEVICE_ADDRESS       (0x29 << 1) // device address, (7 Bit shift left 1)
#define TCS_ENABLE               0x00 // enable reg
#define TCS_ENABLE_PON           0x01 // enable power on
#define TCS_ENABLE_AEN           0x02 // enable ADC
#define TCS_COMMAND_BIT          0x80 // Command Bit (for sending commands to the Sensor)
#define TCS_CONTROL              0x0F // Control Bit (Gain adjust)
#define TCS_ATIME                0x01 // Integration time

// color registers
#define TCS_RDATAL               0x16 // red
#define TCS_GDATAL               0x18 // green
#define TCS_BDATAL               0x1A // blue
#define TCS_CDATAL               0x1C // clear 

// TCS I2C init
extern void tcs_init(); 

// enable sensor ADC and power
extern void tcs_enable(); 

// set integration time to 50ms
extern void tcs_setIntegrationTime_50ms(); 

// set the sensors gain to 1x
extern void tcs_setGain1x(); 

// get RGBC values
extern void tcs_get_rgbc(unsigned int* r, unsigned int* g, unsigned int* b, unsigned int* c);

// write (8 bit)
extern void tcs_write8(unsigned char reg, unsigned char value); 

// read 8 bit
extern unsigned char tcs_read8(unsigned char reg); 

// read 16 bit
extern unsigned int tcs_read16(unsigned char reg); 

#endif /* TCS34725_H_ */
```

tcs34725.c

````c
/*
 * tcs34725.c
 *
 * Created: 26.01.2023 19:45:56
 *  Author: olive
 */ 

#include "tcs34725.h"

void tcs_init()
{
    iic_init();
}

void tcs_enable()
{
    tcs_write8(TCS_ENABLE, TCS_ENABLE_PON);
    _delay_ms(3);
    tcs_write8(TCS_ENABLE, TCS_ENABLE_PON | TCS_ENABLE_AEN);
}

void tcs_setIntegrationTime_50ms()
{
    tcs_write8(TCS_COMMAND_BIT | TCS_ATIME, 0xEB); // 0xEB => 50 ms
}

void tcs_setGain1x()
{
    tcs_write8(TCS_COMMAND_BIT | TCS_CONTROL, 0x00); // 0x00 => Gain = 1
}

void tcs_write8(unsigned char reg, unsigned char value)
{
    iic_start(); 
    iic_send(TCS_DEVICE_ADDRESS | 0x00); // write
    iic_send(reg);
    iic_send(value);
    iic_stop(); 
}

unsigned char tcs_read8(unsigned char reg)
{
    iic_start(); 

    // set reg
    iic_send(TCS_DEVICE_ADDRESS | 0x00);
    iic_send(reg);

    iic_start(); 

    // get 8 bit
    iic_send(TCS_DEVICE_ADDRESS | 0x01);
    unsigned char value = iic_receive(NACK);
    iic_stop();

    return value; 
}

unsigned int tcs_read16(unsigned char reg)
{
    iic_start(); 

    // set reg
    iic_send(TCS_DEVICE_ADDRESS | 0x00);
    iic_send(reg);

    iic_start(); 

    // get 16 bit
    iic_send(TCS_DEVICE_ADDRESS | 0x01);
    unsigned char value = iic_receive(ACK) << 8;
    value |= iic_receive(NACK);

    iic_stop(); 

    return value; 
}

void tcs_get_rgbc(unsigned int* r, unsigned int* g, unsigned int* b, unsigned int* c)
{
    *r = tcs_read16(TCS_RDATAL); // read red
    *g = tcs_read16(TCS_GDATAL); // read green
    *b = tcs_read16(TCS_BDATAL); // read blue
    *c = tcs_read16(TCS_CDATAL); // read clear
}


```
````

Comment: maybe the LCD is defective

Comment: may be the sensor is defective.

Comment: Are you playing with the bare chip, or a completely assembled module? Chip reference: ***TCS3472 COLOR LIGHT-TO-DIGITAL CONVERTER with IR FILTER*** Datasheet- TAOS
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TCS34725.pdf

Comment: If you are using a module, is it a high quality AddAfruit, or a not always reliable cheapie eBay? AdaFruit reference: RGB Color Sensor with IR filter and White LED module (***Discontinued***) - TCS34725 AdaFruit US$8
https://www.adafruit.com/product/1334

Comment: I am doing it with the full assembled TCS34725 module like from Adafruit.

Comment: I am using a bad board (from my school) with no I2C PullUps, could it be that?

Comment: @nosqwhar: Thanks a lot for your confirmation. (1) It is good that that you are using the AdaFruit's fully assembled (and usually well test) module. (2) Question: ***Have you used any utility or short test program to confirm that the I2C module can be detected***?

Comment: @tlfong01 I used an Oscilloscope and measured both the SCL and SDA signals. They don't look that good because of the missing pullUps. I tried reading from the Sensor with a Raspberry Pi Pico, which worked extremely well. However, I don't get it working the Atmega16.

Comment: @nosqwhar: If the module can be detected then, (3) ***have you used your read/write function to confirm you can read any register and read it back***? (4) I would suggest to first test the 0x00 Enable Register. You can write any random value, say 0x5b to it and see if you can then read it back, (5) If above test is OK, you can enable the detect operation and perhaps also the interrupt thing.  (6) If your school has a osciiloscope, you can then see if the module output any interrupt signal if you (a) power on module, (b) switch on any clear LED.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142425/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-nowsqwhat).